# Geb: text() vs value()

Tags: geb

Just a small clarification on using Geb text() vs value().

According to the Geb documentation:

> The value text is treated specially as a match against the node’s text.

And for value():

> Calling value() with no arguments will return the String value of the first element in the Navigator.

From my understanding through trial-and-error, text() can be used to check/set the text content in a particular element, EXCEPT form elements. value() is used to check/set the content of a form element.

```
assertThat($("h1").text()).isEqualTo("Geb")      // will work
assertThat($("input").value()).isEqualTo("Geb")  // will work
assertThat($("input").text()).isEqualTo("Geb")   // will not work
```

Is this correct? Or is there a greater differentiation? I couldn't find any substantial description in the documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `text()` to set anything, it only returns the first element's text content. It basically delegates to [WebElement.getText()](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--).

The text you quoted:

> The value text is treated specially as a match against the node’s text.

Relates to using an attribute selector like `$("div", text: "Lorem ipsum...").

And yes, `value()` and `value(Object)` can be use to retrieve and set value/text of an input.